# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str error, multiple fails after trying debug in a different cell

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two dataframe.
As follows:

[image]

[image]

And I have the following function:

```
def get_user_movies(user_id):
    movie_id = user_movie_df[user_movie_df['UserID'] == user_id]['MovieID'].tolist()
    movie_title = []
    for i in range(len(movie_id)):
        a = movie_title[movie_title['MovieID'] == movie_id[i]]['Title'].values[0]
        movie_title.append(a)
    if movie_id == [] and movie_title == []:
        raise Exception
    return movie_id,movie_title
get_user_movies(30878)
```

And I have the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-9c58c22528ff> in <module>
      8         raise Exception
      9     return movie_id,movie_title
---> 10 get_user_movies(30878)

<ipython-input-55-9c58c22528ff> in get_user_movies(user_id)
      3     movie_title = []
      4     for i in range(len(movie_id)):
----> 5         a = movie_title[movie_title['MovieID'] == movie_id[i]]['Title'].values[0]
      6         movie_title.append(a)
      7     if movie_id == [] and movie_title == []:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I debug couple of times, the line that has error no problem running when I try to run with single movie_id or some random movie_id together in another loop.. I just don't understand why this error keeps poping up..

Please take a look! Thanks!

Comment: missing a closing bracket: `movie_title[movie_title['MovieID']` change to: `movie_title[movie_title]['MovieID']`

Comment: Umm.. I tried, the same error persist...  What about the part == movie_id[i]? Do I need to make modification there as well? @Matiiss

Comment: nevermind I didn't notice it was an evaluation but that would either return True or False, wouldn't it? so in Your dictionary there is a key `True`

Comment: Yes, movie_title['MovieID'] == movie_id[i] this will evaluate true and false. if I add movie_title outside will return me the dataframe that is evaluate to true, I am extracting the title value.. but I am not sure how to fix this error. @Matiiss

Comment: Me neither, I have no idea where exactly is the problem but the error clearly says that You are putting string where there should be an integer, so maybe try replacing a few of those strings with just 0 and try if it works then, otherwise I have no clue

Comment: Actually, I used pysnooper to give me a scope of the function when it runs, it failed at the first index.. I am not sure why, I also tried the first index in the movie_id list in a seperate cell, it works fine.. so I am really not sure what is causing this error.. it's not possible the movie_id is string right, my screenshot showed that column is int64.. @Matiiss

Comment: well try out that combination too, why not? try out all combos of indexes until You either run into another error or solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_user_movies(user_id):
    movie_id = user_movie_df[user_movie_df['UserID'] == user_id]['MovieID'].tolist()
    movie_title = []
    for i in range(len(movie_id)):
        a = movie_title[movie_title['MovieID'] == movie_id[i]]['Title'].values[0]
        movie_title.append(a)
    if movie_id == [] and movie_title == []:
        raise Exception
    return movie_id,movie_title
get_user_movies(30878)
```

movie_title list and movie_title dataframe name repeated..